# list of figures and page numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I made a list of figures at the end of my document and i have a problem. List of figures is longer than one page and i don't want any page numbers on any of these pages.

Unfortunately comands below make page number dissapear only on the last page of the list of figures. How can i remove page numbers on every page of list of figures?

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\listoffigures
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to locally override the behavior of `\chapter*` that issues `\thispagestyle{plain}`.

A hack is to say

```
\cleardoublepage
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\endgroup
```

at the point where you want the list of figures.

A more abstract way is to define a command in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\emptypage}[1]{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \begingroup
  \let\ps@plain\ps@empty
  \pagestyle{empty}
  #1
  \cleardoublepage}
\makeatletter
```

and then say, for instance

```
\emptypage\tableofcontents

\emptypage\listoffigures
```

Comment: Thank you . I will try this as soon as possible and then i ll report back.

Answer (score 3):

Try these:

```
\listoffigures\pagestyle{empty}
```

or

```
\pagestyle{empty}\listoffigures
```

should work. To start numbering again use `\pagestyle{plain}` after some section command or chapter, whatever.

---

**edit:** here is a minimal code to test the effect inserting the command **before/after** the `\listoffigures`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\newpage 
\lipsum[2] 
\listoffigures\thispagestyle{empty} \newpage
\lipsum[4]\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not working.

Comment: @sigur: surely you need the `\pagestyle{empty}` _before_ `\listoffigures`

Comment: @wasteofspace, strange! For me it works. I'll edit.

Comment: @Sigur Impossible: `\listoffigures` issues `\chapter*`, which in turn issues `\thispagestyle{plain}`. So if you put `\pagestyle{empty}` before it, it will be overridden; if you put it after it will hold only for the last page of the list.

Comment: @egreg @Sigur An MWE might be handy, because dozens of classes and packages redefine `\listoffigures`.

Comment: @mafp The hack in my answer uses the current meaning of `\listoffigures`; it just redefines the page styles used to empty. Of course if `\listoffigures` has been redefined to issue itself a `\pagestyle` command, that hack will go wrong. But then it's the OP's job to add information.

Comment: @egreg, I'll edit my answer to show a MWE. But using `\thispagestyle{empty}` or `\pagestyle{empty}` before `\listoffigures` (using the class `report`) the page number was removed only from the page before the list (on the first case) or from the page before the list and so on except the first page of the list.

Comment: Ty for the edited anwser, but it isn't working. I have lots of packages included in preamble...

Comment: @71GA, yes. I believe that my answer is not able to apply the changes inside the `\listoffigures`, but only before it or after it, having no effect on the middle pages.

Comment: @egreg. While the posted hack works as expected, the abstract way just removes the numbering from the following text [i don't use \mainmatter, so it could be somehow connected] (and probably is not closed)

please move to comment on egreg answer

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on answers yet. So here is a small correction to egregs answer:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\emptypage}[1]{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \begingroup
  \let\ps@plain\ps@empty
  \pagestyle{empty}
  #1
  \cleardoublepage
  \endgroup
}
\makeatletter
```

The command should include the `\endgroup` or else all the pages after the command will have no the empty pagestyle.

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to [this one](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1392). However, you may have to repeat the `\thispagestyle{empty}` both after `\listoffigures` and at `\addtocontents{lof}` as follows:

```
\listoffigures  \thispagestyle{empty}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
```